# When running my app with ANT, no XPath implementation can be found

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I wrote an app that uses XPath to query some XML config files. When I run it in eclipse, it works just fine. I also wrote an ant target that runs the application. However, The app gives me a runtime exception when running it from ant. The exception says: 
  `XPathFactory#newInstance failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp.xpath/dom` 
 I'm using JDK 1.6, which is supposed to have already an implementation for XPath. Is there something I'm missing?

Edit 1: Adding the complete stack trace gotten from ANT. I'm using 1.5 compliance.

```
Detected Java version: 1.5 in: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\jre
Detected OS: Windows XP
parsing buildfile C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist\run_lora.xml with URI = file:///C:/Automation/LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int/Tools/LocalizationResourceAnalyzer/dist/run_lora.xml
Project base dir set to: C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist
Build sequence for target(s) `run_all' is [run_all]
Complete build sequence is [run_all, run, ]

run_all:
Project base dir set to: C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist
  [antcall] calling target(s) [run] in build file C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist\run_lora.xml
parsing buildfile C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist\run_lora.xml with URI = file:///C:/Automation/LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int/Tools/LocalizationResourceAnalyzer/dist/run_lora.xml
Project base dir set to: C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist
Override ignored for property config.dir
Override ignored for property report.dir
Build sequence for target(s) `run' is [run]
Complete build sequence is [run, run_all, ]
  [antcall] Entering C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist\run_lora.xml...
Build sequence for target(s) `run' is [run]
Complete build sequence is [run, run_all, ]

run:
     [echo] ant.java.version: 1.5
     [echo] C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Compuware\DLM40JNI.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-antlr.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-apache-bcel.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-apache-bsf.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-apache-log4j.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-apache-oro.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-apache-regexp.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-apache-resolver.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-commons-logging.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-commons-net.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-icontract.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-jai.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-javamail.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-jdepend.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-jmf.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-jsch.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-junit.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-launcher.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-netrexx.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-nodeps.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-starteam.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-stylebook.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-swing.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-trax.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-vaj.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-weblogic.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-xalan1.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant-xslp.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\ant.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\bsf.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\cruisecontrol-antlib.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\js.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\junit.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\statcvs.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\xercesImpl.jar;C:\apache-ant-1.6.5\lib\xml-apis.jar;C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\lib\tools.jar
     [java] Running in same VM Executing 'com.ti.et.swtest.l10n.lora.Lora' with arguments:
     [java] '-conf'
     [java] 'C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist\config\Nspire\product_bundles.xml'
     [java] '-locales'
     [java] 'C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist\config\Nspire\supported_locales.xml'
     [java] '-xrules'
     [java] 'C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist\config\Nspire\exclusion_rules.xml'
     [java] '-loc'
     [java] 'C:\LoRA_Reports\Nspire\localization_report.xml'
     [java] 
     [java] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [java] not part of the command.
     [java] Feb 2, 2010 6:28:07 PM com.ti.et.swtest.l10n.lora.Lora main
     [java] INFO: Localization Resource Analyzer (LoRA) started.
     [java] Feb 2, 2010 6:28:07 PM com.ti.et.swtest.l10n.lora.Lora loadLocales
     [java] INFO: Loading locales from: C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist\config\Nspire\supported_locales.xml
     [java] java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: No XPathFactory implementation found for the object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:180)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:710)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:178)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:84)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:37)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:382)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:107)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:246)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:67)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: No XPathFactory implementation found for the object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom
     [java]     at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(XPathFactory.java:101)
     [java]     at com.ti.et.swtest.util.xml.XmlFile.(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at com.ti.et.swtest.util.xml.XmlFile.(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at com.ti.et.swtest.l10n.lora.Lora.loadLocales(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at com.ti.et.swtest.l10n.lora.Lora.main(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:202)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:134)
     [java]     ... 24 more
     [java] --- Nested Exception ---
     [java] java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: No XPathFactory implementation found for the object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom
     [java]     at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(XPathFactory.java:101)
     [java]     at com.ti.et.swtest.util.xml.XmlFile.(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at com.ti.et.swtest.util.xml.XmlFile.(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at com.ti.et.swtest.l10n.lora.Lora.loadLocales(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at com.ti.et.swtest.l10n.lora.Lora.main(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.run(ExecuteJava.java:202)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:134)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:710)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:178)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:84)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:37)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:382)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:107)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:275)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:40)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1068)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:668)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:187)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:246)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:67)
  [antcall] Exiting C:\Automation\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer-int\Tools\LocalizationResourceAnalyzer\dist\run_lora.xml.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Can you post a larger stacktrace and some more details of your environment (appservers, classpath etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the attribute `fork="true"` to your java task in the ant script so that your class is run in a new java virtual machine. It's likely that something in ant is conflicting with the XML libraries built in to the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

That exception looks like it is coming from the XPathFactory class, so java is finding the correct library. Rather it looks like XPathFactory is crashing. Perhaps [this](http://www.psuedoguru.com/roller/page/psuedoblog?entry=failed_to_create_an_xpathfactory) helps?

Answer (score 0):

- If you have declared a System property or $JAVA_HOME/lib/jaxp.properties for the JAXP property "javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:uri" and assigned the value "http://java.sun.com/**jaxp.xpath**/dom", then I would suggest changing that value to "http://java.sun.com/**jaxp/xpath**/dom".
- If you do have the above property declared correctly, then try removing the property completely.
- If it still does not work correctly, then add some code before you instantiate the XPathFactory to detect which jar the class is being loaded from. "See ClassLoader.findResource(String name)". I see that Ant also packages an xml-apis.jar which has an implementation of XPathFactoryFinder and XPathFactory and maybe this interferes with the classes in JDK.

HTH

Comment: I see no file named `jaxp.properties` anywhere under `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older thread, but [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40955003/xpathfactoryimpl-not-found-error-using-mybatis/44246978#44246978) might shed some light on the issue.  It finds the XPathFactory you specify using a -D parameter that I've never seen documented.